# PySpark, intersection by Key

Tags: pyspark, rdd

for example I have two RDDs in PySpark:

```
((0,0), 1)
((0,1), 2)
((1,0), 3)
((1,1), 4)
```

and second is just

```
((0,1), 3)
((1,1), 0)
```

I want to have intersection from the first RDD with the second one. Actually, second RDDs has to play the role of the mask for the first. The output should be:

```
((0,1), 2)
((1,1), 4)
```

it means the values from the first RDD, but only for the keys from the second. The lengths of both RDDs are different.

I have some solution (have to prove), but something like this:

```
rdd3 = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)
rdd4 = rdd3.filter(lambda((key1, val1), (key2, val2)): key1 == key2)
rdd5 = rdd4.map(lambda((key1, val1), (key2, val2)): (key1, val1))
```

I don't know, how efficient is this solution. would like to hear the opinion of experienced Spark programmers....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps we shouldn't think of this process as join. You're not really looking to join two datasets, you're looking to subtract one dataset from the other?

I'm going to state what I am assuming from your question

1. You don't care about the values in the second dataset, at all.
2. You only want to keep the values in the first dataset where the key value pair appears in the second dataset.

---

**Idea 1**: Cogroup (I think probably the fastest way). It's basically calculating the intersection of both datasets.

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([((0,0), 1), ((0,1), 2), ((1,0), 3), ((1,1), 4)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([((0,1), 3), ((1,1), 0)])
intersection = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).filter(lambda x: x[1][0] and x[1][1])
final_rdd = intersection.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1][0]))).map(lambda (x,y): (x, y[0]))
```

---

**Idea 2**: Subtract By Key

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([((0,0), 1), ((0,1), 2), ((1,0), 3), ((1,1), 4)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([((0,1), 3), ((1,1), 0)])

unwanted_rows = rdd1.subtractByKey(rdd2)
wanted_rows = rdd1.subtractByKey(unwanted_rows)
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is faster than your method. It does require two `subtractByKey` operations, which can be slow. Also, this method does not preserve order (e.g. `((0, 1), 2)`, despite being first in your first dataset, is second in the final dataset). But I can't imagine this matters.

As to which is faster, I think it depends on how long your cartersian join takes. Mapping and filtering tend to be faster than the shuffle operations needed for `subtractByKey`, but of course `cartesian` is a time consuming process.

Anyway, I figure you can try out this method and see if it works for you!

---

A sidenote for performance improvements, depending on how large your RDDs are.

If `rdd1` is small enough to be held in main memory, the subtraction process can be sped up immensely if you broadcast it and then stream `rdd2` against it. However, I acknowledge that this is rarely the case.

Comment: thank you very much. I thought, it should be some method to classify my RDD according keys results. Thank you a lot again.

Comment: I also recommend looking into `intersection`. Right now it seems it only works if the whole row matches, which doesn't work for your use case, but I wonder if you could manipulate `intersection` to work on intersection of key-value pairs only. If I figure it out I will update my answer.

Comment: intersection is a little bit other story, I really looking for intersection for keys, not for the values (is of course what you tell me too). But I will take me a time and analyze your recommendation. Thank you

Comment: I've added some info on `cogroup`, which allows you to match on keys only while maintaining the values.