# Best way to extract and save values with the same keys from multiple RDDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've created two RDDs in PySpark with data extracted from HBase. I want to gather items with the same row keys, store the items and then search through values associated with each of the items. Ideally I'd store the results in a pyspark.sql object, since I want to apply Levenshtein distance to their content.

Details:

In the HBase I have location data, where a row key is the geohash of a given area, and in the columns there are multiple venues in the area with more details (json with description and other text data) on the location.
I have two HBase tables and the locations can be the same in both of them. I want to search the data in those two RDDs, check for similar geohashes and store the results in a new data structure.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I've just started learning Spark, thus I'm wondering: what's the best way to do such task? Is the built-in function rdd.intersection a good solution?

Comment: Your question does try to explain the problem but lacks an example of input/output data, so it's not really re-creatable. Please read [mcve] and further update your question. Thanks.

Comment: @philantrovert Thanks for the suggestion, I've added more details.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704594/4121573)?

Comment: @asettouf Not really, I need to save the data from both sets.

Comment: @Angelika, are the geohash keys unique in each RDD? That is, can the same geohash appear multiple times in either RDD? If they might appear multiple times, both the cogroup and the SQL JOIN implementations suggested so far may produce unexpected results. The cogroup will return a tuple of lists of matching keys, the JOIN will return the cartesian product. https://gist.github.com/WanderingStar/33a72488c6a3140ff001dbbbed918637

Comment: @Aneel, correct, however the `join` on a RDD seems more indicated in that case, depending on the dataset of course. Though I think your approach with dataframes looks better as pretty quickly, the overhead of creating the dataframes is absorbed by the optimization made by Spark

Comment: @asettouf, for me the advantage of DFs is ease of use, not speed of computation. I personally find it much easier to think about labeled columns with a defined schema, and to use SQL-like operations on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited**: Actually thanks to @Aneel's comments I could correct some of my mistakes.
Actually there is a [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs) call on RDDs that gives the same (the join is done on the first column of the RDDs, and the values are a tuple of the rest of the columns of both RDDs), as a call with an `JOIN` with Spark SQL gives out, instead of doing a `cogroup` as previously pointed to, since as @Aneel pointed out `cogroup` squash key-value pair under one single key.

Now on a different note, I tried @Aneel's methods, and the gist above, and try to benchmark it a little bit, here are the results, using databricks' community edition (very small cluster, 6GB of memory, 1 core and Spark 2.1), here is the [link](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/3128577468641144/3883614585456829/3856453658438143/latest.html). (the code is also at the end of the post)

Here are the results:

- For a 100000 sized list:

  - Spark SQL: 1.32s
  - RDD join: 0.89s
- For a 250000 sized list:

  - Spark SQL: 2.2s
  - RDD join: 2.0s
- For a 500000 sized list:

  - Spark SQL: 3.6s
  - RDD join: 4.6s
- For a 1000000 sized list:

  - Spark SQL: 7.7s
  - RDD join: 10.2s
- For a 10000000 sized list (here I called timeit to do only 10 tests, or it will be running until Christmas. Of course the precision is thus decrease):

  - Spark SQL: 57.6s
  - RDD join: 89.9s

Actually it looks like that for small datasets RDDs are faster than Dataframes, but once you reach a threshold (around 250k records), Dataframes join start to be faster

Now as @Aneel suggested, bear in mind that I made a pretty simple example, and you might want to do some testing on your own set of data and environment (I did not go farther than 10M lines in my 2 lists because it already took 2.6 min to initialized).

Initialization code:

```
#Init code
NUM_TESTS=100
from random import randint
l1 = []
l2 = []

import timeit
for i in xrange(0, 10000000):
  t = (randint(0,2000), randint(0,2000))
  v = randint(0,2000)
  l1.append((t,v))
  if (randint(0,100) > 25): #at least 25% of the keys should be similar
    t = (randint(0,2000), randint(0,2000))
  v = randint(0,2000)
  l2.append((t,v))

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(l1)
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(l2)
```

Spark SQL test:

```
#Test Spark SQL    
def callable_ssql_timeit():
  df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1).toDF("id", "val")
  df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
  df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2).toDF("id", "val")
  df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")
  query="SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id"
  spark.sql(query).count()


print(str(timeit.timeit(callable_ssql_timeit, number=NUM_TESTS)/float(NUM_TESTS)) +  "s")
```

RDD join test:

```
#Test RDD join
def callable_rdd_timeit():
  rdd1.join(rdd2).count()
print(str(timeit.timeit(callable_rdd_timeit, number=NUM_TESTS)/float(NUM_TESTS)) + "s")
```

Comment: why do you recreate the table each time? Wouldn't you want to just create it once and query it many times, like you're doing with the RDD? https://gist.github.com/WanderingStar/aa22e166ae19579d2fa2d3767e8598f5 takes 0.28s on my cluster vs 2.1s for the cogroup

Comment: Also, is the `cogroup` example actually doing any calculation? There's no call that prompts it to resolve the lazy evaluation. Try timing `rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).filter(lambda x: x[1][0] and x[1][1]).count()` vs `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id").count()`. Incidentally, counting the results shows that these two operations don't do the same thing.

Comment: I don't think you want a LEFT join either. That will return a row for every row in table1 whether there is a matching row in table2 or not.

Comment: @Aneel The `l2.append` is at the right place as I wanted to ensure at least 25% of identical keys. In the test, I want to take into account the time of creation of the table, because you don't have this overhead when using directly RDDs. Fair point regarding lazy evaluation of RDDs, I corrected this, as well as replacing the call to `cogroup`with a `join`that actually returns the same count as the SQL `JOIN` (really not sure why `cogroup` is not returning the same, besides the iterables...). The `LEFT JOIN`was a typo, good catch!

Comment: I think the difference in the counts between `cogroup` and `join` is because of repeated keys within one of the RRDs. I asked a question on the OP about what should happen if a key is repeated. If the goal is to find all matching keys and treat them as a single group, the cogroup solution may be best (for example, find all venues within a certain distance of each other and consider them a "neighborhood"). If the goal is to find all _pairs_ of matching keys, you want the join (for example, check to see if there are venues in rrd2 that are duplicates of venues in rrd1).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean about the indentation. You only want to generate a new key some of the time. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use pyspark.sql DataFrames, how about converting the RDDs to them at the outset?

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1").toDF("geohash", "other", "data", )
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2").toDF("geohash", "other", "data", "fields")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.geohash = table2.geohash").show()
```

If you want to operate on similar (non-identical) geohashes, you can register a user defined function to calculate the distance between them.

Comment: if it efficient enough to create a new data frame from the whole set if I'm only gonna analyse a part of it?

Comment: Dataframes, like RDDs, are evaluated lazily. The spark optimizer will try to do the operations you request efficiently. What is "efficient enough" for your purposes? I'd suggest trying with a small dataset to get the syntax right and then trying with your full data.

Comment: By the way, given that @Angelika wants to keep records appearing with the same hash in both RDDs, shouldn't it rather be an inner join in your SQL Query?

Comment: JOIN and INNER JOIN are equivalent: only return the rows where there are matching geohashes in _both_ tables.