# pyspark intersection by key and cogroup performance

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm fairly new to Spark and have the following problem:

In a previous job I created two large files where each line holds a pair of ids and a according value e.g.

(id1, id2, value)

First thing I do is reading the files from hdfs and map them to tuples like:

((id1, id2), value)

```
def line_to_tuple(line):
    x = eval(line)
    return ((x[0], x[1]), x[2])

rdd0 = sc.textFile('hdfs:///user/xxx/file1')
         .map(lambda x: line_to_tuple(x))
rdd1 = sc.textFile('hdfs:///user/xxx/file2')
         .map(lambda x: line_to_tuple(x))
```

Q1: Is there are more efficient way to do this? Can I store the data in another way such that I don't have to eval each line every time I read in?

In the next step I use cogroup and then filter out empty results like in this post to then write the results back to hdfs:

[PySpark, intersection by Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701733/pyspark-intersection-by-key)

```
rdd0.cogroup(rdd1).filter(lambda x: x[1][0] and x[1][1])
                  .map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1][0])[0], list(x[1][1])[0]) )
                  .saveAsTextFile('hdfs:///user/xxx/cogrouped_values')
```

The results of the jobs looks like this:

((id1, id2), value_file1, value_file2)

Q2: My code works but it eats up a lot of resources and I've been asking myself if there is any way to further improve given the following assumptions:

1. the files are sorted by id1 and id2 and id1 is always smaller than id2
2. rdd0 << rdd1 (one of the files is much smaller than the other)